# Model Create Method Not Working

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I've the following line of code to determine whether a record exists in the DB, if it does then update it accordingly, if not create it:

```
$test = Result::where('match_id','=',$input['id'])->get();

    if(empty($test)){
        Result::create($result);
    } else {
        Result::where('match_id','=',$input['id'])->update($result);
    };

    return redirect('admin/results');
```

The update section works just fine, however the create element doesn't seem to work. When I strip down and just use create it works fine, so can't figure out the problem

Answer (score 1):

You must set your attributes as fillable in your model:

`protected $fillable = ['a','b'];`

And there is a better way:

```
Result::updateOrCreate(['match_id'=>$input['id']], ['a'=>$input['a'],'b'=>$input['b']])
```

Comment: With that updateOrCreate, will that work as it is or do I have to do somehting like Result::whereId($input['id'])->get(); before I run the updateOrCreate?

Comment: I've set the fillable all fine in the model.

Comment: That must work as it is. [doc](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_updateOrCreate)